# aws ec2 describe-instances not allowed in user-data?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

In order to dynamically build a configuration file, I need to query *EC2* from an instance to retrieve information on existing instances. I use the `aws` *CLI* with the `ec2 describe-instances` flag.
The instance I'm running the command from is attached to a ***role*** that permits such queries:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeRegions",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works perfectly fine when the instance is started, but when I try to fetch data from a `user-data` file, I get:

```
A client error (AuthFailure) occurred when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

I read that this could be caused by a *not-time-synchronized* instance, so I added `openntpd` to the `user-data` file, before calling `awscli`, but still get the same error.
Within the `userdata`, I successfully access to `s3` and `route53` using `awscli`:

```
aws s3 cp s3://s3test/foobar.yml playbook.yml
```

And just to be sure the *IAM* policy was ok, I also tried with *AWS*'s `EC2ReadOnly` policy, and got the same result.

The query is done this way:

```
region="eu-central-1"

for ip in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --debug --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=rabbitmq' --region "$region"|jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddresses[].PrivateIpAddress')
do
    # [stuff to be done]
done
```

Please note this is **not** an authentication failure, I am using **roles** to allow the instance to query *EC2*.

Anyone around using an `awscli` *EC2* access and willing to share experience?

Comment: Have you tried putting a delay in your user-data script before the aws command?

Comment: I've added a `sleep 10` after the _ntp_ synchronization, should be enough but it might not hurt to try increasing it...

Comment: It just seems like the command may be running before credentials are deployed to the metadata service.

Comment: Definitely not a sleep / timing issue, I am able to _ssh_ the instance, cut/paste the exact same query and get a result while the `user-data` keeps trying to fetch it (added a `while` loop)

Comment: Yah, interesting. Honestly I'm out of ideas. I've not seen this before and I use instance roles and user-data aws commands extensively. Hope you're able to get to the bottom of it!

Comment: A friend of mine told me he fell into that trap also, and finally pushed the script containing the `describe-instances` commands to _S3_, fetched it from its `userdata` and executed it. I'll give that option a try. Thanks for caring anyway! :)

Comment: Turns out it seems it's a basic `PATH` issue. `awscli` is installed via `pip` in `/usr/local/bin`, and for some reason, while the `aws` command **does** work and is launched, it _might_ not find another executable when it's doing the `describe-instances` query. Added `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` in the `userdata` file and now I get the instances description.

Comment: Good catch! Go ahead and post that as an answer to your own question, and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment section, I finally figured out this issue was related to a missing `$PATH`.
In my `userdata` script, `awscli` is installed via `pip`, which installs it in `/usr/local/bin`. The `aws` command itself is actually found as it is executed, but there must be a sub-process called within `awscli` when the `describe-instances` function is called that does not know about `/usr/local/bin`, which leads to the previously mentionned error.
The trivial fix for this is to prepend `$PATH` with `/usr/local/bin` in the `userdata` script:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH; export PATH
```